# Have My App Download A File From Link

Tags: android, android-studio, download

Through multiple attempts i have failed to find a working way to display an online database on the app. So i'm going to do it locally. How to make the app to where every x min it downloads and overwrites the file and once done send a push notification when it has updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)?

Great way to save data, and sync it with the [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).